# How to store json data in varibe using ajax calls

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps, asp.net-ajax

I want JSON data to be stored in the variable using ajax calls. How to write ajax call and save JSON data value in variable for showing the data in Google Maps. Need `DustValue` from JSON and should be assigned in variable of Google Maps js.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCLi6lY_WbRa9mkWKc" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(22.8046, 86.2029);
        function initialize()
        {
            var mapProp = {
                center:myCenter,
                zoom:17,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            var DustValue=23;//  ajax call.. $.ajax({url: 'http://xyz.in/dust/get'......
            var dustbinstatus='';

            if(DustValue<50){
                dustbinstatus = 'img/dustbinempty.png';
            } else if(DustValue>50 && DustValue<90){
                dustbinstatus = 'img/dustbinfull.png';
            } else if(DustValue>90){
                dustbinstatus = '3.jpg';
            }

            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myCenter,
                icon: v_icon
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:1580px;height:780px;"></div>
</body>
```

**Sample data:**

```
{"success":true,"sensorsdata":{"WaterTemperature":null,"DustValue":23.00,"DOValue":null,"CurrentTime":"29-August-2016 02:59:AM"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `success` callback handler to store the response in a variable, Here is an example,

```
    var dustValue;    
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "your_url_goes_here",
          dataType: "json",
          success : function(data) {
              dustValue = data;
           }
        });
```

Hope this helps!